# GlassFish deploy war to localhost:8080

Tags: glassfish, localhost, war

Is it possible to have my war deployed to localhost:8080 rather than localhost:8080/mywar

I put the way in autodeploy folder and if I add slash and war name the app loads just fine. Otherwise, localhost:8080 shows some welcome page.

I failed to find info on how to skip it and have my war file deployed to the root.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You can set the context root for your web application in the file `glassfish-web.xml`. If you don't have this file, create it in the `WEB-INF` folder.

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application 
Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This should work for Glassfish 3 and 4. For Glassfish 2 you need a similar file named `sun-web.xml`.

**See also:**

- [Using the context-root from glassfish-web.xml in GlassFish 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216323/using-the-context-root-from-glassfish-web-xml-in-glassfish-3)
- [Setting context root does not work in Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491203/setting-context-root-does-not-work-in-glassfish)
- [Context path for web application on Glassfish 3.1.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853901/context-path-for-web-application-on-glassfish-3-1-2-2)
- [how to Change glassfish application url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231286/how-to-change-glassfish-application-url)